# Create new App using CoreData with AppGroups in mind

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

Hy,

until now I created my iOS Apps that use CoreData by simply checking the "use CoreData" checkbox in XCode and all was good. Lately I decided to dive into multiple targets and using a shared container for my CoreData database. I read thru multiple tutorials explaining the process of creating and using AppGroups.

While I fully understand how to migrate an existing database to the shared container, I can't wrap my head around the process of creating a new app from the ground up the uses CoreData with AppGroups.

- Do I always have to migrate my CoreData model first?
- Is there a way to create the CoreData model in the shared container from the beginning?
- Does that happen automatically?

My current understanding is the following:

1. Create a new XCode project and select "use CoreData"
2. Design your model with the `xcdatamodeld` file in your App's main target
3. Modify `AppDelegate` to point to the shared container
4. Modify `AppDelegate` to perform a migration of the database on the first App launch

Is 4. redundant once I perform 3. before the first ever launch of the app? I know that 4. becomes neccessary if I decide to ship version 1.0 of the app without an AppGroup and follwing versions using AppGroups (and therefor shared containers).

Could it be that easy? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't always need to migrate the data to use app groups. It's a common need because a lot of apps need to switch to using app groups after they've been released, which makes migration necessary. But that's only because the app already has data that's not in the app group. They need to move the existing data.

If the app has never been launched, you can do your steps 1-3 and be done. The persistent store will go into the app group from the start. It won't need to be migrated into the app group because it will already be there. Even if you implemented step 4, it would have no effect.

Xcode's project template, as you've noticed, doesn't cover app groups, but you seem to know how to fix that.